# Error "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tcp_nodelay'" on python 2.7

Tags: django, macos, python-2.7, typeerror

I am here again guys, I am running a django app on MacOS and when I star the server everything goes well but when I try to access to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/`

I got:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tcp_nodelay'
    Request Method: POST
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/
    Django Version: 1.11
    Exception Type: TypeError
    Exception Value:    
    __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tcp_nodelay'
```

I am using python 2.7 and Django 1.11
I tried recreating my virtualenv but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the answer referenced by [nthall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354176/nthall):

0

I had the same error, and in my case that was an issue related to the cache settings in the settings.py file, please check that maybe you have something like this in the options key for your cache settings

```
CACHES = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': '-----',
    'TIMEOUT': 30000,
    'KEY_PREFIX': CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX,
    'OPTIONS': {'ketama': True, 'tcp_nodelay': True}
```

I removed the options and it worked for me

Regards !!

Answer (score 1):

There is a [similar question with an unaccepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46293803/error-running-django-local-server-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argumen) pointing at `settings.py` and specifically the `CACHES` setting. I can't link it as a potential duplicate because the answer hasn't been accepted, but it's a great place to start -- search your `settings.py` (or, your entire code dir) for `tcp_nodelay` and try removing that option if you find it.

Comment: Thanks nthall I reviewed and it worked, I am new on stackoverflw I don't know If I should delete the question

Comment: usually better not to delete! just upvote helpful stuff and accept an answer and move on.